# Override react env variable from docker-compose

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose, create-react-app

I created my react app using `create-react-app`. 
I defined by variables within `.env` file

```
REACT_APP_BACKEND_BASE_URL=http://localhost:8001
```

I built my app using `yarn build` and I store it into `docker` image.

I'd like to override it from my `docker-compose` file:

```
...
    environment:
      - REACT_APP_BACKEND_BASE_URL=http://localhost:8010
```

but once the container starts still use it the value from the `.env` file.

I wonder if is it possible to override it from `docker-compose` file or if the only choice is to set/use a dedicated `.env` file at building time.

Answer (score 0):

Rename you app .env to .env.development

If this doesn't work add .env.production for build time vars.

See https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#what-other-env-files-can-be-used

Comment: removing the .env file uses the host of the react app: IOW the environment variable provided via compose file is ignored or is not properly setted. 
.env.production works, but that's what I'd prefer to avoid